# C# Fetch User Public IP

Tags: c#

I am trying to get The Public IP of the current user using C# Console App

this code has worked so fine

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://checkip.dyndns.org";
        System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        string[] ipAddressWithText = response.Split(':');
        string ipAddressWithHTMLEnd = ipAddressWithText[1].Substring(1);
        string[] ipAddress = ipAddressWithHTMLEnd.Split('<');
        string mainIP = ipAddress[0];
        Console.WriteLine(mainIP);
    }
```

but the problem is I don't want to use an external/third-party website to get the Public IP, I want a C# code that doesn't use any website to get the Public IP (if Possible).

Comment: Tricky. Your c# app would likely be running on a device that is behind a firewall. The app is not necessarily privy to the external IP of the firewall.

Comment: on windows you can run ipconfig and parse the output, that may point at your router

Comment: @Hogan - that is usually the LAN address from DHCP not a static IP.  The address seen by external sites is set by some combination of (proxies, routers, modems, gateways) so going to an external site and having that return your IP might be the only way for a general-purpose method.

Comment: @DaveS -- yes I agree with you and Chris on this point, I wanted to mention ipconfig because that is clearly a good way if you need this functionality for an internal network.

Comment: The address an external site sees is the definition of your public IP. It's common for your local device to have no knowledge of it.